# Method not allowed while using ajax put request asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller, put

I have the following **AJAX** request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/newrentals",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "PUT",
    data: columnDate
}).done(function() {
   toastr.success("Rentals succesfully recorded.");
}).fail(function() {
   toastr.error("Something unexpected happened.");
});
```

And here's my **CONTROLLER:**

```
using System.Web.Http;  //I used the correct reference 

public class NewRentalsController : ApiController {

       [HttpPut]
       public void updateRentalReturnDate(string columnDate){
            var date = columnDate; 
       }
}
```

When I hit some button, the ajax request is executed but it does not reach the controller. I get the following error :

> "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."

I have read many answers but nothing helped me. For instance, I made sure that the paramater name in ajax and in the controller should be same. I also put the [HttpPut] annotation in the controller method. What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try to set url like  "/api/newrentals/columnDate", and without data

Comment: I tried it and it worked. So why does it not work when we set the data attribute in ajax? Isn't the controller parameter supposed to be reading from the ajax data attribute?